# blog system with xml

Tags: php, html, xml

i am creating a blog system, i made two sections with new_post write the post and insert in xml and delete_post write the title of post and delete  from xml

here is for new_post:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    $xml= new DomDocument("1.0","UTF=8");
    $xml->load('writeblog.xml');

    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $Body=$_POST['body'];

    $rootTag=$xml->getElementsByTagName("root")->item(0);

    $infoTag=$xml->createElement("info");
        $titleTag=$xml->createElement("titlu",$title);
        $bodyTag=$xml->createElement("continut",$Body);

        $infoTag->appendChild($titleTag);
        $infoTag->appendChild($bodyTag);

    $rootTag->appendChild($infoTag);
    $xml->save('writeblog.xml');
}
?>
```

here is my form

```
<form method="post" action="new_post.php">
    Add new Post</br>
    <label>TITLE: </label><input type="text" name="title" />
    <label for="body"> BODY </label>
    <textarea name="body" cols=50 rows=10></textarea>

    <br />

    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="POST" />
</form>
```

and delete_post:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    $xml= new DomDocument("1.0","UTF=8");
    $xml->load('writeblog.xml');

    $title=$_POST['title'];

    $xpath=new DOMXPATH($xml);

    foreach($xpath->query("/root/info[titlu='$title']") as $node)
    {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
    $xml->formatoutput=true;
    $xml->save('writeblog.xml');
}
?>
```

and here is my xml:

```
<root> 
    <info> 
        <titlu> 
        </titlu>  
        <continut>  
        </continut> 
     </info> 
</root>
```

so my question is : how i can read now from the xml file and insert in the blog home page post by post like be my first post , second post

Comment: With the same `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: yes but i don't know how to write them in the blog like first post , second post . the first info to be in the first post

Comment: Get attributes of a node and echo them.

Comment: ok , i will try , thank you !